# Show that $\frac{\partial u}{\partial \eta} = \frac{\partial u}{\partial r} = 2r \cos 2 \theta$

Tags: calculus

> Let $\Omega$ be a $k$-connected Jordan domain and $u$ a harmonic function in $\mathcal{C}^2(\Omega^{+}).$ Then $$\int_{\partial \Omega} \frac{\partial u}{\partial \eta}(z) ds = 0.$$

I'm trying to verify this theorem for $u(x,y)=x^2-y^2$, $\Omega = D_{R}(0)$ (disk of radius $R$ centered at the origin).

Work so far:
First I converted $u(x,y)$ to polar form $u(r,\theta)=r^2 \cos 2 \theta$. Now I need to show that the normal derivative $\frac{\partial u}{\partial \eta} = \frac{\partial u}{\partial r} = 2r \cos 2 \theta$ for positively oriented circles centered at the origin.

This is where I'm a bit stuck. I think it's obvious that $\frac{\partial u}{\partial r} = 2r \cos 2 \theta$ (just take the first partial of $u(r,\theta)$ with respect to $r$), but I'm having trouble showing this for the outward normal derivative. Using the definition, we have $\frac{\partial u}{\partial \eta}= \nabla u(r,\theta) \cdot N(r,\theta)$ where $\nabla u$ is the gradient and $N(r,\theta)$ is the normal vector at the point $(r,\theta) \in \partial D_R(\theta)$. So $\nabla u(r, \theta) = (u_{r},\frac{1}{r}u_{\theta})=(2r \cos 2 \theta, -2r \sin 2 \theta)$ and since our domain is a circle centered at the origin, the normal vector at the point $(r,\theta)$ is just the vector $(r,\theta)$. Thus $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial \eta}= \nabla u(r,\theta) \cdot N(r,\theta) = (2r \cos 2 \theta, -2r^2 \sin 2 \theta) \cdot (r, \theta) = 2r \cos 2 \theta \cdot r -2r \sin 2 \theta \cdot \theta. \hspace{1mm} (\star)$$

**Q1:** How does the expression $(\star)$ equal $2r \cos 2 \theta$?

In the next step we are asked to fix $r = R$ and then show $\frac{\partial u}{\partial r} = 2 R \cos (2s/R)$. From the above, we know that $\frac{\partial u}{\partial r} = 2r \cos 2 \theta$. If $R=r$, set $s=R \theta$. Then $\frac{\partial u}{\partial r} = 2r \cos 2 \theta = 2R \cos (2s/R)$.

**Q2:** Is the work here correct?

Comment: For Q1 you need to revisit what is the gradient in polar coordinates. This is where you are going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Note that
$$ \frac{ \partial u } { \partial n} =  \nabla u \cdot n = \frac{\partial u}{\partial r }$$
when $n$ is the normal for a disk (draw a picture, which way does the normal point).
Since $u = r^2 \cos 2 \theta$, we easily see that $\partial_r u = 2r \cos 2 \theta$. Your second question follows easily now.